# How to show that the sinc function series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\text{sinc}(x+n)$ is equal to pi for all $x$?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, sequences-and-series

We know the very well-known identity:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\text{sinc}(n)=\pi.$$
But how to show that
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\text{sinc}(x+n)=\pi, \qquad \forall x?$$

Comment: this is indeed a remarkable result: no matter how much you shift your sample points on a sinc function, the sum of those samples is constant. For a derivation, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242280/what-is-the-sum-over-a-shifted-sinc-function